# Variables nulled on dismissViewController

Tags: nsdate, viewcontroller

I have a view controller with a date picker, and set variables to the picked date.

When I dismiss the view controller, the variables are nulled.

Any suggestions?

DatePickerView code when 'done' is pressed (NSLogs show the date is assigned to the variables):

```
-(void)done:(id)sender
{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

    AddEditFixturesTableViewController *fixtures = [[AddEditFixturesTableViewController alloc]init];

    fixtures.fixtureDateTime = pickerDateTime;

    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy"];
    NSString *pickerDateTimeString = [formatter stringFromDate:pickerDateTime];
    NSLog(@"Picker Date: %@", pickerDateTimeString);
    NSString *fixturesDateTimeString = [formatter stringFromDate:[fixtures fixtureDateTime]];
    NSLog(@"Fixture Date: %@", fixturesDateTimeString);
}
```

Code when I check if the date is assigned (NSLogs show the variables are null):

```
DatePickViewController *pickerView = [[DatePickViewController alloc]init];

NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy"];
NSString *fixturesDateTimeString = [formatter stringFromDate:fixtureDateTime];
NSLog(@"Fixture Date: %@", fixturesDateTimeString);
NSString *pickerDateTime = [formatter stringFromDate:[pickerView pickerDateTime]];
NSLog(@"Picker Date: %@", pickerDateTime);
```

Comment: How do you get your `pickerDateTime`? `pickerDateTime = [_picker date]`?

Comment: when the picker value changes, pickerDateTime = picker.date;

Comment: It looks like everything okay, I think something wrong in your DataPickViewController and code that isn't shown here has bug. If you want, send your .h and .m files to me.

Comment: First trouble is your date property can be nil if user hasn't changed date.

Comment: yep i know that, will sort that once its working - but when i do change it, it's still nil.

Comment: Hmm... I've just tested it and it works.

Comment: This is my output:

2013-07-28 17:48:21.113 DVFC[3266:c07] Picker Date: 02-08-2013
2013-07-28 17:48:21.114 DVFC[3266:c07] Fixture Date: 02-08-2013
2013-07-28 17:48:24.163 DVFC[3266:c07] Fixture Date: (null)
2013-07-28 17:48:24.164 DVFC[3266:c07] Picker Date: (null)

Where the date is shown, that is in the first code block, and the null are in the 2nd.

Did your output all show dates?

Comment: Did you look at code below? In answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your mistake is in following code:

```
AddEditFixturesTableViewController *fixtures = [[AddEditFixturesTableViewController alloc]init];
fixtures.fixtureDateTime = pickerDateTime;
```

Here you initialize new AddEditFixturesTableViewController object and set property to it. But you have to set this exactly to your exist object. So you have to use delegation.

First you have to do it's add protocol. Add following to your DatePickViewController.h:

```
@protocol DatePickViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>

- (void)setNewDate:(NSDate *)date;

@end

@interface DatePickViewController : UIViewController

{
    IBOutlet UIDatePicker *datePicker;
}

@property (nonatomic, weak) id<DatePickViewControllerDelegate> delegate;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIDatePicker *datePicker;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSDate *pickerDateTime;

-(IBAction)done:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)dateChanged:(id)sender;

@end
```

Now fix your `done:` method.

```
- (void)done:(id)sender
{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

    if (_delegate) {
        [_delegate setNewDate:pickerDateTime];
    }

    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy"];
    NSString *pickerDateTimeString = [formatter stringFromDate:pickerDateTime];
    NSLog(@"Picker Date: %@", pickerDateTimeString);
    NSString *fixturesDateTimeString = [formatter stringFromDate:[fixtures fixtureDateTime]];
    NSLog(@"Fixture Date: %@", fixturesDateTimeString);
}
```

In your `AddEditFixturesTableViewController` interface add delegate method.

```
@interface AddEditFixturesTableViewController : UITableViewController <UITextFieldDelegate, UITextViewDelegate, DatePickViewControllerDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSDate *fixtureDateTime;

@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UILabel *label;
- (IBAction)setDate:(id)sender;
- (void)setNewDate:(NSDate)date;

@end
```

And finally add delegate method implementation:

```
- (void)setNewDate:(NSDate *)date
{
    fixtureDateTime = date;
}
```

It will help you. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the help - but that causes the app to crash.

Comment: Thanks for this. however, I haven't needed to do this anywhere else in my app, and I've done the same things, but used unwind segues.